# Object's properties info

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

There is an API to get object's properties for model.

```
GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties
```

But it returns only names of the properties. How can I get type (integer, string, ...) of property and some additional info (precision for numeric, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only API endpoint that deals with properties, so unfortunately there is no way to achieve that with the REST API at the moment.

One workaround would be to extract all resources for a model using the API, take a look at the following article: [Forge SVF Extractor in Node.js](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs).

Once you downloaded the resources, take a look at the `section_properties.db`, which is a sqlite database, from there you can recompose which properties belong to which component and will be able to get their type, you will access the same information than what you can get in the viewer, there is no way to access the precision as far as I know, as I mentioned in your previous question.

Here is how that file looks in an sqlite db viewer, you would need to do a bit of fiddling around in order to find what you are looking for:

[image]